# Complexity of else block containing loop inside a loop block

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm trying to find the frequency of each statement and the big o of this method.

But I'm struggling with the else part, I know that we take the worst complexity of if and else

But logically, in this case, do I have multiply the frequency of the outer loop (n) by the frequency of the else loop (n+1) ? Although I know that the else block will be executed for one time only, when i=0
But when we follow the rules we have to multiply it 
So I'm stuck here and I don't know what to do in this case, I hope you guys could help me
Thanks!

```
int i, j, sum = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
if ( i != 0)
    Sum += i;
else
    for (j = 0 ; j< n; j++)
        Sum + = j;
```

Comment: No In this case complexity will be 2n. as n times else loop and n times main loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have a O(n) loop and a O(n) else inside it.
But in your code, we only go through the else statement once.

So you have a for loop, and inside the if you do O(1) work (n - 1) times, and once (i == 0) you do O(n) work ( when the else statement is reached )

So the complexity would be O(n) = (n - 1) * O(1) + O(n) ~ O(2n) which is also O(n) because we drop the constants when doing asymptotic analysis.